# Tour Planning (Shift Full Utilization)

Tags: here-api, here-tourplanning

I am using the Tour Planning API to route multiple trucks to deliver many orders.
The problem I am trying to solve currently is fully utilizing all of the trucks.
Let's say we have 100 deliveries to make and 7 trucks. I want the API to attempt to use all trucks (shifts). Currently, it will, at times, use 6 trucks or however most efficiently to route. This makes sense when cost savings is your only goal. The goal of our solution is also to take into account Driver Retention. If we have 7 drivers, we need to use all 7 drivers.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not yet available in the Tour planning production version. In the future, we may provide this feature where users would be able to ask Tour planning to utilize the maximum possible number of vehicles. Which in turn will use all vehicles if the number of jobs is more than the number of vehicles. Please contact HERE support or your HERE account executive to provide more input on your requirements